# Passing props via <Link> tag to separate page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react site in which I need to pass some props via a Link tag.
I have set up my link tag and have some props contained within there(aboutProps object).

Here is this code.

```
  <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/admin-view-full-user-wsa-responses",
                aboutProps: {
                  WSAId: this.props.WSAId
                }
              }}
            >
              <button>View Full Details</button>
            </Link>
```

AS you can see I am trying to pass WSAId through to the component.

This is then the component I am trying to pass this through to

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../codestone logo.png";

import NavBar from "../PageDetails/Headers/NavBarUsers";
import LogOutButton from "../PageDetails/Buttons/LogOutButton/LogOutButton";
import ProfileButton from "../PageDetails/Buttons/ProfileButton/ProfileButton";
import AdminButton from "../PageDetails/Buttons/AdminButton/AdminButton";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
// this console logs as undefined
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.location.aboutProps);
    console.log(this.props.location.aboutProps);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />  
      </>
    );
  }
}

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
        <ProfileButton />
        <LogOutButton />
        <AdminButton />
      </div>

      <div className="User-Menu"></div>
      <img
        className="profile-image"
        alt="icon"
        src={logo}
        width="340"
        height="60"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass them using `state` instead of `aboutProps` like so:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/admin-view-full-user-wsa-responses",
    state: {
      WSAId: this.props.WSAId
    }
  }}
>
  <button>View Full Details</button>
</Link>
```

And access it with:

```
this.props.location.state //in a class component

props.location.state //in a functional component
```

Comment: This simply returns the error "props is not defined"

Comment: `this.props` because you're using a class component

Comment: tried that aswell but nothing is returned. When console logged it is still undefined

Comment: Fixed was syntax.Your answer is correct I will mark you as answer. Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Why not pass WSAId as a URL param ` pathname: "/admin-view-full-user-wsa-responses"+ this.props.WSAId` and use `props.match.params` to extract it in child. This will preserve state during reload as well.

Comment: @ssk that comment should be on the question, not this answer. And no problem Henry, thanks